# Is header in legend valid? <legend><h1>Caption</h1></legend>

Tags: html, header, legend

I use this in visual studio but the compiler claimed that `h1` cannot be nested in `legend` element, but browser can render it anyway so i am confused that this is valid or not?

```
<fieldset>
   <legend>
     <h1>Caption</h1>
   </legend>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many things that browsers do that aren't required by the standards :-)

This page [here](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/forms/legend.html) (HTML4) specifies the `legend` keyword and states that it can contain [inline elements](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/inline.html), of which the headers are not a part. It does have other possibly useful ones such as `big` or `strong`.

In addition, the relevant page for [H1](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block/h1.html) does not list `legend` as one of the items it's allowed to be contained within. You may also be able to use the `id`, `class` or `style` attributes of the legend to set the underlying textual properties.

Comment: I find it helps to understand that one major use of `fieldset` and `legend` besides grouping fields is that screen readers for the sight impaired (the ones i have used anyway) will read out the legend text when focus is set into an input control in the fieldset so that the user knows they are editing "Personal Information - Name", "Personal Information - Date of Birth", etc. If you need to be section 508 compliant you may want to consider keeping `legend` contents simple text and use CSS to style it.

Comment: Addendum to this - `h1` inside a `fieldset` basically has the same semantic effect as `legend` in HTML5. This is because `fieldset` is defined as a "sectioning root", and `h1` defines the label/subject of a sectioning root. So drop those impossible to style `legend` tags in favor of `h1`.

Answer (score 11):

In HTML 5.2, this seems to be valid:

> 4.10.16. The legend element
>     Content model:
>       Phrasing content and headings (h1-h6 elements).

https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#the-legend-element

This is very good news, as in complex forms, legends serve the same purpose as headings do, and e.g. screenreaders only announce legends when focusing a form element.

Comment: You can forego legends entirely for screen readers by utilizing `role="group"`.

Comment: To keep backwards compatibility, I prefer having "real" HTML tags instead of ARIA attributes.

Comment: The group role is compatible with all screen readers, since the inception of JAWS support in IE8. There were no screen readers for IE7. Plus it allows the freedom of not having to deal with the odd styling quirks of the legend element.

Comment: That's right, the legend element is nasty. Still, I prefer not to use role, if a standard element can be used. But it's good to know that one can use it if HTML <5.2 is used.

Answer (score 6):

In HTML5 elements allowed inside `<legend>` elements are those in the [Phrasing Content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#phrasing-content) group. Per the docs:

> Phrasing content is the text of the document, as well as elements that mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level.

Answer (score 3):

no it is not valid inside the legend. you can use [wc3 validator](http://validator.w3.org) to validate your code

Answer (score 3):

The legend element of the fieldset is not designed to allow child elements unless they are considered "phrasing content". While most browsers will not complain (thus making it valid in pratice) you would probably be better off using a style to set the look/feel of your legend element as that is what css is for, elements should be used for logically grouping/identifing content not styling it.

> Legend: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-legend-element
>
> Phrasing Content: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#phrasing-content

Answer (score 2):

if you check the html standards it says:

```
<!ELEMENT LEGEND - - (%inline;)*       -- fieldset legend -->
```

The `%inline` part means that it should only contain character level elements and text strings. So while it does render, you should not use it this way because the html is actually not valid.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5, you can use an `<h1>` for the same purpose a legend serves in a fieldset, since a fieldset is considered a sectioning root. So if you want to be free from the legend's wonky styling quirks, use this accessible markup:

```
<fieldset role="group" aria-labelledby="heading">
    <h1 id="heading">Caption</h1>
    <p>Other stuff...</p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as stated in the [WHATWG spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-legend-element) and [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend), permitted content for the `<legend>` element includes both [phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content) and [heading content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#heading-content).