# Seo Heading when can't use heading tags

Tags: seo, semantics, html-heading

I've got a few places on my page where I can't use heading elements due to semantic HTML but I need them there for SEO. Or at least something that will help the SEO. I know I can't just add an H3 nearby and hide it as the bots might flag it.

So for example I need a fieldset with legend for accessibility. But I need the legend to contain a H2 for SEO but can't because of semantics.

Or I have tiles that are links that need H3 in them but can't for the same reasons as above. Not sure how I'm going to solve this issue or what I can do.

Comment: [You can't put a heading in a legend tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005887/is-header-in-legend-valid-legendh1caption-h1-legend). But a legend is the perfect, semantic element for explaining the contents of a fieldset, and will certainly help with SEO. Why do you say you "need" an h2 or an h3?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about seo

Answer (score 0):

It's ridiculous how much people overthinking on page SEO. First of all, out of all heading tags, the only tag that actually brings decent value is H1. The rest is just whatever.

My advice is to focus more on keyword density - keep the your main key term(s) for that page at around 4-6% density and if you have supporting terms (supporting keyword cloud) keep it at 2.5% but not any higher.

Do not waste your time and overthinking what to do if you can't put h2 or h3. Just make sure you have H1 (ultimately, keep your main keyword at the beginning of the header tag and you will be good)